# Cancel or recover crashed repair / upgrade (innovation) install (phase 0) on Windows XP Pro SP3

Tags: windows, repair, sp3, windows-xp

I had some errors and problems in Windows, so I tried automatic repair from Windows.
That failed and I get error:

> Internal Setup Data Structures are corrupted(phase 0)

I searched the net, tried the unattended install WINNT.SIF [Data] parametres, nothing helped.

I have swapped harddrives and made new install, so I have full access to the old Windows harddrive for easier analysis and/or repair.

**Error specification:**   (lines that are translated to English are marked so at the end)
    ***C:\WINDOWS\setupact.log***

> External program RUNONCE -r returned code 1.
>   (...)
>   SetUpVirtualMemory: EXIT (1)
>   System file [c:\windows\system32] cannot be copied to system cache memory of DLL. (Translated)
>   This file can be neccssary to maintain the stability of the system. (Translated)
>   (...)
>   Warning Uninstall: Failed to retrieve registry entries
>   Warning Uninstall: Failed to retrieve registry entries
>   Warning Uninstall: Failed to retrieve registry entries
>   (...)
>   Internal Setup Data Structures are corrupted(phase 0)

***C:\WINDOWS\setuplog.txt***    (d:\ is the CD-ROM drive)

> File,Line,Tag,Message
>   (...)
>   d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\syssetup.c,1938,,Setup: (non-critical error): Failed load of ismif32.dll.
>   (...)
>   d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup  \syssetup.c,2053,BEGIN_SECTION,Processing parameters from sif
>   d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\cmdline.c,228,,SETUP: SpSetupLoadParameter was unable to find msdosinitiated.
>   d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\cmdline.c,632,,SETUP: Upgrade=0.
>   d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\cmdline.c,633,,SETUP: Unattended=0.
>   d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\cmdline.c,228,,SETUP: SpSetupLoadParameter was unable to find uniqueness.
>   d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\cmdline.c,228,,SETUP: SpSetupLoadParameter was unable to find AccMagnifier.
>   d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\cmdline.c,228,,SETUP: SpSetupLoadParameter was unable to find AccReader.
>   d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\cmdline.c,228,,SETUP: SpSetupLoadParameter was unable to find AccKeyboard.
>   d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\log.c,133,,Internal Setup Data Structures are corrupted(phase 0).
>
> d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\log.c,133,,Critical error
>   d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\log.c,133,,:
>
> d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\log.c,133,,Internal Setup Data Structures are corrupted(phase 0).
>
> d:\xpsp\base\ntsetup\syssetup\log.c,133,,
>
> ---

Curently I'm looking for a way how to make repair process functional, or a way to disable the repair while making the system usable by manualy moving files, etc.

Is there anyone with a tip (add a comment), or a solution to this?

Comment: Why not just backup your data (since the drive is accessible) and clean install on the old hardrive?

Comment: Precisely set workplace, and very complicated. I have set up temporary install on similar machine, thought.

Comment: Why did you attempt a repair in the first place?

Comment: Crashed drivers by interfering installation of new graphics driver and hence unable to use an recovery option from the system itself.